# java script traffic light sequence timer

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img id="Change Lights" src="red.jpg" width="1500" height="800"> 

 <br><button onclick="nxt()" id="button">Change colour</button></br>

 <script>

var img = new Array("red.jpg", "amber.jpg","green.jpg");



var imgElement = document.getElementById("Change Lights");
var lights = 0;
var imgLen = img.length;

             function nxt()
        {
            if(lights < imgLen-1)
                {
                    lights++;
                }
            else{
                    lights=0;                
                }

                imgElement.src = img[lights];                    
        }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

hi this is my code I'm really stuck on how to add a timer I have researched how to do a timer but I still cant figure it out,so that the traffic lights change by itself, please could you help me by giving a timer to add or complete it with a timer.

Comment: Settimeout and/or Setinterval are what you need ;) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp / http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval(nxt, 1000) to change the color every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: By testing maybe ? Or searching a minimum in Google ? You have a new lead, now you can try to advance by yourself and come back if you encounter new problem amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

All contributors said the truth. `setInterval` saves the day.

It seems that you want to create a traffic lights.
https://jsfiddle.net/tyf5rjk3/

P.S. Just a little remark. `Javascript` is written as one word ;)